# Javascript date validation from current date to before 3 years

Tags: javascript, validation

I am new to javascript and request help.I have two dates start date and end date on my page. I want to throw a validation error through javascript if the user picks 3 years before the current date for the start date and 3 years after the current date for the end date.

How should I handle this? I tried the following,

```
var a1 = Date.parse(startDate);
var b1 = Date.parse(endDate);
var mydate=new Date();    
var c1 = Date.parse(mydate);    
var diff1 = c1-a1;
var daysCal1 = diff1 / 1000 / 60 / 60 / 24;
var days1 = Math.ceil(daysCal1);
if (days1 > 1095) {         
      //throw the exception

}
```

Comment: What do you mean exactly in throw an exception?.
Does your logic is the problem(diff no calculated properly) or are you asking how to display the error?.
If it is the second option, please share your DOM structure(HTML)

Answer (score 0):

Well, assuming you've stored the start date as a1 and end date as b1, you could use the *.valueOf() for date objects for your comparison (see http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_valueof_date.asp)

So you could do something along the lines of:

```
var currentDate = new Date();
var currentMinus = currentDate.valueOf()-(3*365.25*24*60*60*1000); //or use +94672800000 
var currentPlus = current.Date.valueOf()+94672800000;
if (a1.valueOf() < currentMinus) {
    //should execute if a1 is more than 3 years prior to current date/time
}
if (b1.valueOf() > currentPlus) {
    //should execute if b1 is more than 3 years after current date/time
}
```

I didn't test all of this as is, but should work for you or at least give you the concepts to use in your own code/situation